# Update AD Attributes of multiple users

Tags: active-directory

I want to add the siteCode attribute to all users in a specific OU but I can't find a way to do this in the GUI.

Is there any other way to achieve a mass update like this? I've seen scripts on line but I will not use a script downloaded from the internet on my corporate network.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use LDAP, e.g. via Perl's `Net::LDAP`, or OpenLDAP's `ldapsearch` + `ldapmodify` (with some additional shell-script glue).

1. Search AD for something like `(objectCategory=user)` with the wanted OU as "base".
2. For each result, send a "modify" request which replaces (or adds) the wanted attributes.

For example:

```perl
$res = $conn->search(filter => "(objectCategory=user)",
                     base => "ou=IT,dc=example,dc=com",
                     attrs => ["1.1"]);

for my $entry ($res->entries) {
    $conn->modify($entry->dn,
                  replace => { myAttribute => ["value 1"] });
}
```

Async updates & error checking left to the reader.